Why Use Refresh Tokens in Authentication? Can't They Be Stolen Like JWTs?
I'm implementing authentication in my app using ASP.NET Web API and JWTs. I’m trying to understand the purpose of refresh tokens and have some doubts about their benefits and security implications:
Why should we refresh tokens at all? Why not just have long-lived JWTs that last as long as refresh tokens? Wouldn’t that be simpler?
If a hacker steals the refresh token, can’t they just use it to get new access tokens (and even a new refresh token)? Doesn’t this defeat the whole purpose of token refreshing?
I noticed companies like Facebook and others use session-based authentication with tokens that last up to a year. Why don’t they use refresh tokens, and how do they secure these long-lived sessions?
Here’s what I’m doing currently:
When a user logs in, I validate their credentials, generate an access token (valid for 10 minutes) and a refresh token (valid for 1 week), and return both to the client as HttpOnly cookie.
I store the refresh token in the database along with metadata (e.g., userId, IP address, creation date, and expiration date).
When the access token expires, the client sends the refresh token to a specific endpoint to get a new access token and refresh token.
On refresh requests, I validate the IP address in the request against the one stored in the database for the refresh token. If they don’t match, I deny the request.
I also have a revoke endpoint that deletes the refresh token from the database, effectively invalidating it.
Here’s the part that confuses me:
Even if I rotate refresh tokens and validate IPs, if a hacker steals the refresh token, they can still use it for up to a week. Isn’t this almost the same as just having an access token with a 1-week expiration time?
I recently tested Instagram and noticed that their session IDs don’t seem to validate context fully. For example, I logged in, retrieved my session ID, and used it on another machine without any issues. If a hacker gets that session ID, wouldn’t they have access to my account for over a year? That seems risky.
I also wanted to explore session-based authentication (like the ones used by Facebook, Instagram, etc.), but I don’t fully understand how they work or how they manage long-lived sessions securely.
So, I’d love a clear explanation of:
Why refresh tokens are used and how they enhance security.
How to prevent misuse of refresh tokens if they’re stolen.
How session-based authentication works in big companies and how they manage long-lived sessions securely.

This question is similar to: What is the purpose of a "Refresh Token"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The authentication system may use different approach on how Access and Refresh token are used. Splitting responsibilities allows systems to be highly scalable.
A very typical example for an Access token use case is to validate the token on a resource provider - for example, a resource provider may make a local decision for validity based on a public/private key usage.
Access tokens with resource-local verification allow high scalability of systems, but they have a drawback - if an access token is compromised, there is no easy way to revoke it.
Refresh token's usage has much lower frequency, hence a highly scalable system has more option to deal with it. Typically, an authentication system would verify if a refresh token is still valid and it is not revoked. Such decision requires a strongly consistent data source, e.g. a list of revoked tokens. As a result, this affects scalability.
If all authentication decisions are made in centralized way for both access and refresh tokens, then there is no real security benefit for a refresh token. Some system still keep both just to have a scaling out option open.
